# @font-face not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, fonts, font-face

I use @font-face for all my projects and for some reason it is not working in IE8. You can view the site here:  http://milkandhoneyhospitality.com/

As you can see in normal browsers, the main font is Bebas Neue, and it is being rendered perfectly. BUT, when we bring it into ie8, it uses a fallback font, arial. It even works great in IE7, so so IE8 is the issue (Screenshot at bottom)

My @font-face is typical:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Any idea why this wouldn't be working in IE8 ONLY?

[image]

Comment: please ignore question! Clearing my cache fixed the issue. Not sure why it happened to begin with!

Comment: You can answer yourself then accept, or delete

Comment: I have to wait 2 days, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the IE8 Cache solves the issue